# Functional equation book for olympiad

Tags: reference-request, functional-equations, contest-math

what may be the good suggestions in olympiad  functional equations for a beginner for . I have heard of this book by B.J.Venkatachala  but do not whether it will be suitable  for me or not. Anybody already having his book please reply... I really need to improve my problem solving skills in this.

Feel free to add tags.

Answer (score 5):

There is the functional equations training book by Andreescu and Andrica, and the functional equations book by Chris Small. Both are good, and contest-oriented. Have not seen the book mentioned in the OP.

Comment: andreescu's book is too advanced for me as it statrs directly assuming that the reader already know how to tackle functional equation problems I have christopher's book its beginning didnt impress me much as it gives two variable equation before introducing one variable . will check it out. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Some general purpose books might be useful. I liked Engel's Problem Solving Strategies.

Comment: now after more than a year of studying from Engel, I can say- that this indeed proved to be a very useful book